# resizing cards on hover makes the div below jump

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I'm resizing the cards in the `.main-partners` div on hover so the `see more`button appears.

My problem is when I `:hover` over the cards ( `.main-card`) in the `.main-partners` div the `divs`in the `.partners` row below are pushed down.

That is not the effect I'm looking for. I want all cards and divs to stay in place when the resizing happens.

I've spent all morning on trying to fix this by changing the .css back and forth. I'm out of hope now.

Can anyone take a look at this and see what I'm missing.
here is a link to a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/t08bvrwz/13/)

below is my code

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 0; }
  .card .card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0; }


@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 2vh; } }

.main-partners {
  padding: 7px 0 40px; }
  .main-partners .row {
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px; }
    .main-partners .row [class^="col-"] {
      padding-left: 8px;
      padding-right: 8px; }

.main-card {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit; }
  .main-card .card-text {
    color: #4b4b4b; }
  .main-card .more-link {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
    margin-top: -5px; }
    .main-card .more-link span {
      color: #4b4b4b;
      display: block;
      padding: 7px 0 3px;
      border-top: 1px solid lightgray; }
      .main-card .more-link span:before {
        content: '+ ';
        color: #c2002d;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 4px; }
  .main-card:hover {
    margin: -11px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
    .main-card:hover .more-link {
      height: 31px; }

/* partners */
.partners {
  padding: 7px 0 120px; }
  .partners .row {
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-right: -8px; }
    .partners .row [class^="col-"] {
      padding-left: 8px;
      padding-right: 8px; }
  .partners .item {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 137px;
    text-align: center;
    color: inherit; }
    .partners .item figcaption {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 24px;
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      padding: 2px 10px 8px; }
    .partners .item .logo {
      height: 50px;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -moz-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -moz-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center; }
      .partners .item .logo img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%; }
      .partners .item .logo .text {
        display: block;
        font-size: 24px;
        line-height: 34px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 14px 0 0; }
    .partners .item .more-link {
      width: 142px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-weight: 500;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
      -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
      transition: all ease 0.3s;
      margin-top: -5px; }
      .partners .item .more-link span {
        display: block;
        padding: 7px 0 3px;
        border-top: 1px solid lightgray; }
        .partners .item .more-link span:before {
          content: '+ ';
          color: #c2002d;
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: top;
          margin-left: -20px;
          padding-right: 4px; }
    .partners .item:hover {
      margin: -11px -8px;
      height: 159px;
      box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
      .partners .item:hover .more-link {
        height: 31px; }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners {
    padding-bottom: 60px; } }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .partners {
    padding-bottom: 40px; } }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners .row [class^="col-"] {
    padding-bottom: 16px; } }

@media (max-width: 1219px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 14px; } }

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 16px; } }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 14px; } }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container main-partners"> 

  <div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
      </div>
        </a>
    </div>


     

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
      </div>
        </a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
      </div>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




  <div class="container">

  <div class="partners">
<div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
       <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">      
    <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
      <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- partners -->

    <!-- / event-area -->
</div>
```

Comment: You need the hover to work like the  same way it works for the divisions with partners on it  ?

Comment: Yes basically, which it does but the problem is the movement of the .parent div when the cards in the .main-partners div is hovered

Comment: There is no such .parent div in the code that you have provided and any divisions do not move in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this line on hover, the divs no longer jump :)

**margin: -11px 0px;**

So it should be:

```
    .main-card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); 
    }
```

**Update**

To fix the Partners hover as well, I recommend also removing the same MARGIN style as before, setting the height to hover and rather than a fixed height, use something like {height: auto} with {padding: 20px 0;}

Please see my example below for the new classes:

**NEW CSS**

```
.partners .item {
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
```

Codepen Link Here: 
https://codepen.io/CTBroon/pen/OJLXjLB

**Update**

The fix: 
If you want to stop the top section pushing the Partners div down you will need to set a fixed height for the container around it to account for the extra height on hover.

Comment: it still pushes down the .partners div on hover

Comment: Try the same for the '.partners .item:hover' class and for this one set the height to :auto rather than a fixed height.

Comment: it still moves the .partners div.   and if I move the margin: -11px 8px;  from the .partners the whole :hover style goes out of balance.

Comment: I'm not sure if the hover it self is the problem

Comment: If you want to stop the top section pushing the Partners div down you will need to set a fixed height for the container around it to account for the extra height on hover.

Comment: thank you... that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the same pattern for `.main-partners` as you followed for `.partners`. Create a  new `div` and add `.main-partners` in that. In CSS with `.main-partners .card: hover` use that and its working now.
Here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugz9b53p/) link

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ?

```css
.card {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.card .card-img-top {
  border-radius: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 2vh;
  }
}

.main-partners {
  padding: 7px 0 40px;
}

.main-partners .row {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}

.main-partners .row [class^="col-"] {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.main-card {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
}

.main-card .card-text {
  color: #4b4b4b;
}

.main-card .more-link {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.main-card .more-link span {
  color: #4b4b4b;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 0 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.main-card .more-link span:before {
  content: '+ ';
  color: #c2002d;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.card:hover {
  margin: -11px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card:hover .more-link {
  height: 31px;
}


/* partners */

.partners {
  padding: 7px 0 120px;
}

.partners .row {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}

.partners .row [class^="col-"] {
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.partners .item {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 137px;
  text-align: center;
  color: inherit;
}

.partners .item figcaption {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 2px 10px 8px;
}

.partners .item .logo {
  height: 50px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.partners .item .logo img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.partners .item .logo .text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 34px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 14px 0 0;
}

.partners .item .more-link {
  width: 142px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.partners .item .more-link span {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 0 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.partners .item .more-link span:before {
  content: '+ ';
  color: #c2002d;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -20px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.partners .item:hover {
  margin: -11px -8px;
  height: 159px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.partners .item:hover .more-link {
  height: 31px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .partners {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners .row [class^="col-"] {
    padding-bottom: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1219px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .partners .item figcaption {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

.col-sm-12 {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container main-partners">

  <div class="row flex-row">



    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>




    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
      <a href="#" class="main-card">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam..</p>
            <footer class="more-link">
              <span>See more</span>
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="container">

  <div class="partners">
    <div class="row flex-row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <a href="#" class="item">
          <figure>
            <div class="logo">
              <strong class="text">Partner</strong>
            </div>
            <figcaption>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
              irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</figcaption>
          </figure>
          <footer class="more-link">
            <span>see more</span>
          </footer>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- partners -->

  <!-- / event-area -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show "show more" button without pushing other divs,
Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/o7xf60h8/)

just added following some css rules:

```
.main-card {
    position:relative;
}
.more-link{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: good solution, but not exactly the look I'm working with, thank you

Comment: Bro as a good developer you only need a hint to solve your problem not the entire solution, as here I can introduce how it works but at the end  you have to take the changes up according to your need.